# Mahout score matrix state changed

Tags: matrix, state, mahout

I want to use mahout which should help me with next:
I have matrix with users, items and preferences.
And  we have all scores filled up for all users and items. Then preference scores are changed for some user for some items. The problem is how after state changes recalculate other user scores which might have impacted by recent operation?

For example:

```
  state before        state changed         state after recalculation

 u1 item1 25          u1 item1 25           u1 item1  ??
 u1 item2 12          u1 item2 12           u1 item2  ??
 u1 item3 10          u1 item3 10           u1 item3  ?? 
 u2 item1 25       => u2 item1 25     =     u2 item1  ??
 u2 item2 12          u2 item2 12           u2 item2  ??
 u2 item3 10          u2 item3 10           u2 item3  ??
 u3 item1 25          u3 item1 20*          u3 item1  20 
 u3 item2 12          u3 item2 15*          u3 item2  15 
 u3 item3 10          u3 item3 10           u3 item3  10
```

Comment: In theory, every score has changed a little after one update. It's not clear what you're asking a result. Add some details.

Comment: Yes, you are right that every value has changed. The point is that I would like to achieve smth like that from mahout: u1 item1 25.5,  u1 item2 13, u2... and then I would replace from column(state before)     u1 item1 25  to  u1 item1 (25+25.5)/2=25.25, etc.. So I will get next approximation state of user's attributes pereferences..

Comment: It seems unclear what you are trying to achieve. Is it that the preference of users change over time and you want to rebuild the recommender model so that the recommendations generated use the new preference values? Or is it that when a preference of a user for an item change, you want to keep some sort of average as the preference value? Or is it something different?

Comment: Your first statement is correct(preference of users change over time and you want to rebuild the recommender model). It's because scores entered earlier might not be really good (firsts approximations). That's why after all I would want to update model with rest of scores by formula (old+recalculated)/2

Comment: Sean, any ideas over this topic? Looking forward your comments..

Answer (score 0):

Mahout will not adapt the recommendations in an online manner when the preferences change, in essence you would need to give Mahout the complete updated datamodel file and ask it again to recalculate the recommendation model and retrieve the recommendations from it, so basically as a sort batch process.

Kind of like:

- File1 -> Mahout -> Recommendations
- (File1 + changes in preferences) -> File2
- File2 -> Mahout -> Recommendations

Comment: It works well when we have blanks in item scores for particular user. How make it work when all scores are set? Mahout doesn't want to make recommendations in that case :)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If you have scores for every user for all items, then why do you need a recommender? The purpose of the recommender is typically trying to predict future interactions of users with items they have yet not interacted with.

I must ask, how do you determine the value of preference of a user for an item? Is it an explicit rating the user gives to the item? Or how do you approach this?

Comment: Answering your questions: Scores are set based on implicit user preferences and of course are only raw prediction (approximation). To make them more precise it would be good to recalculate them based on every change made to the system.. And then we will have more and more precise approximations based on system evolving..     I was thinking on following(see figure with matrices): Iterate over all users most similar to user 3 (u3) and remove all item1 and item2. Recalculate scores for those items for each user. Сalculate arithmetical mean value. Store. But this is very time consuming approach...